# number of bytes available given address bus width and various information

Tags: math, memory, address-space

A processor has

- 24 bit address bus
- 16 bit data bus
- word contains 2 bytes
- byte addressable
  Peripherals and memory units will be connected and the entire memory space most likely will be used.

There are quite a few questions and I only ever use the fact that there is a 24 bit address bus.

What is the total number of addressable locations for the system? 2^24
1/4 of the address space is to be used for the peripherals, what is the total number of addresses for peripherals? 2^24/2^2
12/16 of the addresses are to be used for disk addressing, how many? (12/16)2^22
3/4 of the address space are to be used for memorey requirements of RAM and ROM, what is the total number of addresses avaliable? (3/4)2^24
This seems to easy

Comment: So what is your question? (BTW, that sounds like an 8086).

Comment: My question is am I doing it right? Is it just a red haring to give us the data bus, the word size and the fact that it is byte addressable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for one answer (which might be a typo), your math is correct.

1. What is the total number of addressable locations for the system? `2^24 = 16,777,216`
2. 1/4 of the address space is to be used for the peripherals, what is the total number of addresses for peripherals? `2^24/2^2(?) = (1/4)2^24 = 4,194,304`
3. 12/16 of the addresses are to be used for disk addressing, how many? <strike>(12/16)2^22</strike> `(12/16)2^24 = (3/4)2^24 = 12,582,912`
4. 3/4 of the address space are to be used for memorey requirements of RAM and ROM, what is the total number of addresses avaliable? `(3/4)2^24 = 12,582,912` (same as 3.)